# Search a json object and update it

Tags: c#, json

I am having the following Json object

```
   [


{
    "ID": 21,
    "Name": "Clement Rakesh",
    "DOB": "1983-07-07T00:00:00",
    "DOJ": "2014-07-30T00:00:00",
    "Address": "BANGALORE",
    "Mobile": 9611795983.0,
  },
  {
    "ID": 34,
    "Name": "Clement Rakesh",
    "DOB": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "DOJ": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Address": "BANGALORE",
    "Mobile": 0.0,

  }
]
```

What i have done so far is :

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FILENAME))
 {
    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
    JToken v = JArray.Parse(s);
    var emp = v.Where(x => x["ID"].ToString() ==empmodl.ID.ToString()).ToList();
  }
```

where FILENAME is the path for file containing the above mentioned JSON object.
The emp contains the required object to be updated.
Now i need to updated the emp information in the original JSON object .
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

1. Deserialize your JSON to an object
2. Edit the object
3. Serialize back to JSON

> ```
>  var input = s;  
>
>  //step 1
>  dynamic yourJson = JObject.Parse(input);
>
>  //step 2
>  yourJson[0].Name = "test";
>
>  //step 3
>  string updatedJson = yourJson.ToString();
> ```

Comment: you could elaborate on some (de)serialization solutions (eg ServiceStack, Json.NET, ...)

Comment: could you please help me by providing the code , as I am new to JSON

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just parse the whole JSON into objects, modify everything you need and serialize it again ?

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FILENAME))
 {
    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
    dynamic jsonObject = JObject.Parse(s);
    var emp = v.Where(x => x["ID"].ToString() ==empmodl.ID.ToString()).ToList();

    //do the modifications here
    //write the contents to the file by using this
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
  }
```

Comment: @user3894583 just gave it here :) I don`t know what modifications you want to make